# How do you debug react-native in 2022?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-debugger

I'm using expo SDK 45 (the latest at the moment i'm writing this) and it seems remote debugging is not possible with [react-native-reanimated 2](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs#known-problems-and-limitations). I'm not even using this library, but [react-navigation's drawer does](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#installation). And as far as I know, many people use react-navigation.

Don't tell me everybody is using Flipper, because I never managed to make it work properly.

I miss react-native-debugger so much..

Can you guys share your favorite debugging tool for react-native ?